# C# JSON Variable Name reserved

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to access nodes "Nodes" of following JSON:

```
{
  "Nodes": [ "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "IDxx" ],
  "Results": {
    "ID1": {
      "ID2": {
        "value1": "example1",
        "value2": "exempleHexa"
      },
      "ID3": {...
```

with these lines:

```
 var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonData);
 var MyNodes = ((JObject)json.Nodes).Children().ToArray();
```

but I get this error message:

> Message=Unable to convert type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Is there a way to access this variable without modifying JSON data?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than "compiler is a bit confused"? Perhaps show the error message?

Comment: Why is this on hold? I already answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nodes` is a `JArray`, not a `JObject`, so cannot be casted as such.

Try this:

```
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonData);
        var nodes = ((JArray)json.Nodes).ToObject<string[]>();
```